# Displaying Wordpress category images with category

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, categories

I have this bit of code:

```
<div class="wrap sc-cat-container">

        <?php
            $customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('short_courses');

            if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
            {
                 foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
                 {
                     $args = array(
                          'orderby' => 'name',
                          'show_count' => 0,
                          'pad_counts' => 0,
                          'hierarchical' => 1,
                          'taxonomy' => $tax,
                          'title_li' => '',
                          'hide_empty' => FALSE
                          );

                        $categories = get_categories( $args );
                        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                            echo '
                            <div class="one-half sc-cat-items">
                                <h2>
                                    <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>
                                </h2>

                            </div>';
                        }



                 }
            }
        ?>

    </div>
```

This displays a list of categories for my custom post type 'Short Courses' Here's how it looks currently: http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/short-courses/

This is great and works fine but I would also like to add images for my categories, I it to look like this:

[image]

I have Advanced Custom Fields, where I have created an image field so I can now assign an image to each category. So far so good!

The main problem comes when I try and display the image inside the code above...

Here's the code that would display the image in any normal circumstance:

```
<img src="<?php the_field('course_type_image'); ?>">
```

But I guess I need to add it to the above code... so I came up with this but it isn't working as I don't t think I can put a php tag inside another PHP tag!?

```
<div class="wrap sc-cat-container">

        <?php
            $customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('short_courses');

            if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
            {
                 foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
                 {
                     $args = array(
                          'orderby' => 'name',
                          'show_count' => 0,
                          'pad_counts' => 0,
                          'hierarchical' => 1,
                          'taxonomy' => $tax,
                          'title_li' => '',
                          'hide_empty' => FALSE
                          );

                        $categories = get_categories( $args );
                        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                            echo '
                            <div class="one-half sc-cat-items">
                                <img src="<?php the_field('course_type_image'); ?>">
                                <h2>
                                    <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>
                                </h2>
                            </div>';
                        }

                 }
            }
        ?>

    </div>
```

So I'm a bit confused...

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to echo a string, but within your string, you are calling a function that itself echos rather then returns, a string:

```
echo '
<div class="one-half sc-cat-items">
    <img src="<?php the_field('course_type_image'); ?>">
    <h2>
        <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) 
                    . '">' . $category->name . '</a>
    </h2>
</div>';
```

Therefore, when trying to call the function [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) within your string to be echo'd, it is attempting to echo again.

You need to return the value of the field instead, with the [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function.

Also, remove the php tags in the img source line, since you are already within an opening `<?php` tag:

```
'<img src="' . get_field('course_type_image') . '">'
```

Comment: Tanks a lot for this chuuke! :) That seems to work to a certain extent, it outputs <img src=""> but it seems to be having issues pulling through the URL...

Do I need to add anything after the course-type-image? For example: get_field('course_type_image', 'SOMETHING HERE') - to tell it that the course-type-image is located inside the short_courses custom post type?

Comment: I thought something like this might work but it doesn't... <img src="' . get_field('course_type_image', $customPostTaxonomies . '_' . $categories) . '">

Comment: What object have you added the "image field" to, with WCF? To a category? To a post? The second argument to get_field is the $post_id, so if you've added custom field to the 'short_courses' post type, ensure that you are within the post Loop (https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), or explicitly pass a post id into the get_field function.

Comment: I'm sorry, chuuke, I don't really understand what I need to do... I have since made a bit of progress here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955622/acf-display-image-from-custom-post-type-custom-category/46957582#46957582 But im still struggling to display the image

Comment: chuuke - The image field is added to a custom taxonomy that I created for my post type short courses. The custom taxonomy is called Course Types rather than Categories.